# How to select from a list and map the another object using Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nested, automapper

From the nested Entity list we want to select an object and map it in the Dto object, but when we use the Automapper to filter for object which deleteDate is equal `null` and map it, for each column Automapper filter again on db. how to filter one time and map selected to Dto object

We need to store all the information in our database so use DeleteDate column with default value `null`. so we use one to many relation to store history of our data.

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public IList<CustomerDetail> CustomerDetails { get; set; }
}




public class CustomerDetail
{
    public Guid CustomerDetailId { get; set; }

    public float MaximumAmountPerTransaction { get; set; }

    public float MaximumAmountPerDay { get; set; }

    public bool IsConfirm { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTimeOffset CreateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTimeOffset? DeleteDate { get; set; }
}




public class CustomerResponse
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CustomerId{ get; set; }

    public string MobileNumber{ get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public bool IsConfirm { get; set; }

    public float? MaximumAmountPerTransaction { get; set; }

    public float? MaximumAmountPerDay { get; set; }
}



public class CustomerDomainProfile : Profile
{
    public UserDomainProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, CustomerResponse>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerId,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Country,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Country.CommonName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.IsConfirm,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>      src.CustomerDetails.FirstOrDefault(cd => cd.DeleteDate ==  null).IsConfirm))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.MaximumAmountPerTransaction,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerDetails.FirstOrDefault(cd => cd.DeleteDate == null).MaximumAmountPerTransaction))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.MaximumAmountPerDay,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerDetails.FirstOrDefault(cd => cd.DeleteDate == null).MaximumAmountPerDay))
    }
}
```

I expect a query to the database and select the CustomerDetails with DeleteDate is null and map it, but the type of our define, for each column trying to query to database because

I expect that querying the database and selecting CustomerDetails with DeleteDate is `null` and its map, but our definition, for each column, is trying to query the database because it can not recognize that they are from a same table. How can we identify them that have fallen from a row to reduce the query? is any other solution or idea?

Comment: Use AutoMapper profiles if your mapping is straightforward, ie. property X maps to property Y, barring some optional conditions. 
In your case I would not use AutoMapper to map these fields

Comment: I tried to use the linq and it has the same problem, ie. the query that is created with the linq will also query the members of each nested column.@Sangman

Comment: Update your question with the LINQ code you wrote